# Keep parent active when hover on the child element CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to keep parent element active, when hover on it's child element. This is my code.

```
<nav class="desktop-menu">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a title="Business Lines" href="#">Business Lines</a>    
       <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu sub-nav">
         <li><a title="Energy" href="#">Energy</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>    
   </u>
</nav>

.desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #67686b;
}
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    border: none;
    background: #67686b;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #FBB914;
}
//Css to keep parent active
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu:hover .desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #67686b;
}
```

Can anyone help me how can i achieve this? 
Thanks is advance.

Comment: I double checked, there is no duplicate css in the code.

Comment: You got a typo error on a closing tag: `</u>`

Comment: usually if you are hovering a child also the parent is hovered: could you prepare a fiddle so we can see exactly the issue? what do you mean by "active"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add some CSS as given below. Hope this will help you.

```css
.desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #67686b;
}
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    border: none;
    background: #67686b;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #FBB914;
}
//Css to keep parent active
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu:hover .desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #67686b;
}
.navbar-nav li{
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav li ul{
  display:none;
}
.navbar-nav li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
.navbar-nav li:hover a{
  color:#fff;
  background: #67686b;
}
```

```html
<nav class="desktop-menu">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a title="Business Lines" href="#">Business Lines</a>    
       <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu sub-nav">
         <li><a title="Energy" href="#">Energy</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>    
   </ul>
</nav>
```

You can also check this https://jsfiddle.net/kdwcbpy9/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to match the hover action to the "li" parent element instead of the "a" tag, in that way you can also match the children, just like the example

```css
.desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li:hover >a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #67686b;
}
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 220px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #FBB914;
}
//Css to keep parent active
.desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li:hover .desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #67686b;
}
```

```html
<nav class="desktop-menu">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a title="Business Lines" href="#">Business Lines</a>    
       <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu sub-nav">
         <li><a title="Energy" href="#">Energy</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>    
   </u>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `.dropdown-menu` is a child of the `li` you're hovering,
there is no need for your last lines of CSS code.

Here is a working snippet of what I think you try to achieve:

```css
.desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #67686b;
}

.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  min-width: 220px;
  /* removed below
  position; absolute
  top: 100%; */
  border: none;
  background: #67686b;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.desktop-menu li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block; /* Appear when hovering */
}

.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  color: #FBB914;
}

/* You don't need this code
.desktop-menu .dropdown-menu:hover .desktop-menu .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #67686b;
}*/
```

```html
<nav class="desktop-menu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a title="Business Lines" href="#">Business Lines</a>
      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu sub-nav">
        <li><a title="Energy" href="#">Energy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps.